# css & html5: why does my body have a spacing at the top?

Tags: css, html

I don't get it. I have …

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

However my browser is always showing the vertical scrollbar even if the content is not as hight as the window.

In the following screenshot you can see that there is this little spacing on top if I inspect the  `body`. The `html`does not have this spacing.

Any idea what could cause that?

[image]

Comment: I think your problem will be in your markup as opposed to the CSS, do you have extra spaces or lines above the body?

Comment: is there any other content/tags inside your body?

Comment: Any chance we could get the full HTML Source? Maybe there's something illegitimate in your `<head>` (for example, a `<br />` for some reason) that is causing the whitespace. I know that I had this problem with WordPress-generated code for around three months before I worked it out.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You probably have an element with `margin-top` as one of the first children of `body`.

Read up on [collapsing margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

Purely as a *simple test*, set `padding: 1px` on `body`. If the gap goes away, I'm right.

Comment: Helped me, although the test didn't work. I put padding: 1px into body but the gap stayed there. I searched for a first-child element with a top margin anyways and found and removed the margin from it --> the gap disappeared.

Comment: Trick worked for me... helped me see a div so obvious I was completely overlooking it.

Comment: This still happens in 2021, and your test worked flawlessly. But is there a "clean" solution to this problem? At least on my webpage, my navbar has a margin-top.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the conversation, but thought this might help some...

If this a WordPress based site, it is likely that WordPress is adding:

```
 html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
```

It is doing this in order to make space for the admin bar, which, apparently, for some reason isn't showing up.

To resolve this, add the following to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this for a completely different reason: I was inadvertently inserting textual characters (specifically, semicolons) in the head, which were somehow translated into the body, where they were hidden by other markup and/or css. But, the space remained.

In my case, neither the body itself, nor any obvious first-child elements had any top margin or padding. Extra text did show up as the first (textual) child of the body, however it did not exactly correspond to the text I needed to remove in order to solve the problem. Specifically, I saw the following text, with a lot of extra white-space:

```
<body>
";




<!-- rest of stuff here -->
```

Note that I am using an HTML templating engine (specifically Razor), so all bets are off as to *how* this transmutation from `; ;` to `";` occurred.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```